# How to filter JSON Data from an AngularJS $http request using an ng-model input

Tags: json, angularjs, filter, angularjs-http, angularjs-orderby

I am struggling with a problem that I think may be down to the scope I am working within. I use a $http request to get some json data.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('PeopleController', function($scope, $http) {
var url = 'https://sweltering-fire-6061.firebaseio.com/people.json';
$http.get(url).success(function(data) {
    $scope.people = data;
});
```

The data displays fine within my table:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in people | filter:query | orderBy:orderBy">
        <td>{{person.name}}</td>
        <td>{{person.born}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p>
   <select ng-model="orderBy">
      <option value="name">Name</option>
      <option value="born">Birth</option>
   </select>
</p>
<p>Search:<input ng-model="query"/></p>
```

However since I stated retrieving the data with a $http request my filter and orderBy no longer work. Is this because I am setting `$scope.people = data` within a lower scope. If it is, is there someway I can work around this?

I have tested this in Cloud9 IDE and Brackets. Thank You

Comment: what type of field you are trying to "orderBy" ? could you post the JSON structure as well?

Comment: @Linial the structure is here: https://sweltering-fire-6061.firebaseio.com/people.json. the values under the options refer to the structure of the json data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you return is not correct, the output of the url:

> https://sweltering-fire-6061.firebaseio.com/people.json
>   is:

```
{"0":{"born":1791,"name":"Charles Babbage"},"1":{"born":1955,"name":"Tim Berners-Lee"}
```

Which means: object.0 = {"born":1791,"name":"Charles Babbage"}
You might want to return an array, because it now tries to filter on "born" or "name", while those attributes are one layer deeper in your objects!

Comment: Thank-you, this was the issue. But it was caused by my posting new data to the json, this added numbers for some reason. Do you know why?

Comment: When you post multiple objects, you have to explicitly say it's an array, otherwise the JSON while just create a JSON object out of it. When you parse your result back to JS, it will be a weird collection of objects in an object, instead of an Array. Always use the square brackets [] or new Array() in JavaScript.